# Determining the correct usage of "reminds" vs "remind"

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> We celebrate all the shapes, colors, texture, and fun that **remind us** of what it was like to be a kid.

Should it be *remind us* or *reminds us*? I'm pretty sure it should be "remind", simply because there are multiple things that are reminding us. But wife claims otherwise, so need to settle this! The fact that the enumeration ends with the word *fun* is I guess the point of contention.

It probably also should be *textures* instead of *texture*, but that may be a different argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

> all the shapes, colors, texture, and fun

is plural — the *and* is a dead giveaway — then the antecedent of the relative pronoun *that* is plural and the verb must be the plural *remind*.

Whether *all* is singular or plural is [determined by what follows it](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp):

> All [of] the cake is gone.
>
> All [of] the pancakes are gone.

Your wife is under the impression that if the last element is singular, then the verb should be singular as well, but there is no such rule:

> All the cookies, Danish pastry, and pecan pie *are* gone.

There is, however, such a [rule](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) for (*either*) *or* and *neither/nor*:

> Either the students in the 10 am class or their professor, should he arrive early, is in for a big surprise.
>
> Neither Prof. Schmidt nor his students are aware that their usual classroom has been flooded.

But *and* always makes a plural except in singular compounds like *bed and breakfast*.

PS: The word *texture* is used here to mean the uncountable quality rather than individual instances of texture, much as one would say that color is a quality of light.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I did not have a good grasp of the either/or rule, which can lead to puzzling sentences (per examples in your link).

Comment: The trick there is just to keep the plural last if at all possible.